# Children's fantasy novel involving rune magic

Tags: story-identification, magic

I'm looking for the title of a book, its details are:

- Children's book series.
- All people live on an island surrounded by fog.
- Boy is chosen to be trained as a magician and is picked to be trained by the head of the guild.
- Magicians use magic by casting rune magic, wither by formation of the hands into the symbols or drawing them inside a formation.
- Upon graduation, magicians are chosen to enact a spell to travel to the other world, where magic still works but is different.
- There are orcs and people, and I think I remember goblins of some sort living underground, both in that other world and on the island!
- In that world, there is a main bad guy, who everyone is afraid of.
- It turns out that main bad guy is actually the head of the guild in disguise.
- The boy battles him and sends him up into the stars.

**What is the name if this book?**

Comment: A fantasy novel with orcs, runes, magic and wizards? Is the answer "all of them ever written"?

Comment: Sounds like fun!

Answer (score 3):

### Could this be [*Quadehar the Sorcerer*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0439536480)?

[image]

This is the first book in the series *Book of the Stars*. It fits most of the information in the question.

- The protagonist lives on a hidden island between the Real World and the Uncertain World.
- The protagonist is a boy of about twelve, who is chosen by the head of the guild.
- The head of the guild is probably Charfalaq, the Chief Sorcerer:

  > The provost addressed the Chief Sorcerer. “Chief Sorcerer Charfalaq…”

  [TV Tropes](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Literature/BookOfTheStars) says of Charfalaq:

  > Charfalaq/The Shadow. He manages to be the Big Good and Big Bad at the
  >   same time.

  This indicates that Charfalaq is also the Shadow, the chief antagonist.
- Magic is done through Graphems, which are basically runes. From TV Tropes again:

  > Quadehar gives many details on how to invocate the runes alphabet in
  >   order to construct gladrs ( spells), runes that are based on
  >   constellations shapes.
- There are korrigans who live underground, and orcs from the other world
- I seem to recall a spell to travel to the Uncertain World, as mentioned in the question. In the Uncertain World, magic works differently:

  > He stopped in midsentence. It was as clear as daylight. “I get it! The Graphems they invoke for their ceremony are those of the Lost Isle! In the Uncertain World, they are different shapes because the constellations are slightly distorted in a different sky! That’s why the Graphems I called up when I was in the market at Ferghana and in Thunku’s palace looked so odd, and neither Isaz nor Thursaz reacted as I expected!”